# Assign text column a new unique int column

Tags: excel

Is there an easy way to take a text column of values and assign a unique int column to it?

**Given**

```
Label3
Label2
Label7
Label3
```

**Expected**

```
Label3,1
Label2,2
Label7,3
Label3,1
```

**Note:** Id column can't be obtained by substringing because the labels can be very random.

Comment: You have said id column so I am assuming the "," denotes column separator i.e. left column Label, right adjacent column id.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use match function

```
=MATCH(A1,A:A,0)
```

To work just with the populated part of column A:

```
=MATCH(A1,OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA(A:A),1),0)
```

---

**Data:**

[image: Data]

Comment: Hi, I was wondering how it came up with the id's they seem to be random...just curious. The answer is exactly what I needed though, thank you.

Comment: Match function returns the position in the array where the value passed as first argument is  ***first*** found. So, when you pass Column A's value as an array with A:A , and attempt a search for Label3, for example, it is first found at position 1 in the array. Label2 is first found at position 2 etc.

Comment: You should probably wrap the whole thing in an IFERROR(....,"my error response") in case value not found.